# Spring load parts of one config with different loaders from file and classpath

Tags: spring, configuration

Is it possible load custom part of config from file and automatically load other part of config from classpath, placed inside jar?

I have command line apllication written on java with spring 2.5.6 framework.
Config of apllication consist from 2 parts:

1. bigApplicationContext.xml
2. customConfig.xml with import of bigApplicationContext.xml

bigApplicationContext has references to some beans from customConfig.

I placed bigApplicationContext and default customConfig inside jar. Configs loaded by ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. It's OK

Troubles goes when I want provide additional command line option for my application --pathToCustomConfig

I want to load custom part of config from file and automatically load other part of config from bigApplicationContext, placed inside jar.

Is it possible? Now I have

> Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative
>   location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution with using

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
```

I used

```
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```